# Introducir variable en expresiones regulares

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy intentando pasar una variable a una expresion regular (para asi poder modificarla a mi gusto) en este caso quiero introducir un numero para que me controle el numero de digitos permitidos .

No consigo hacerlo funcionar , ni pasandolo como un string aparte... nada.
¿Alguna idea?

Gracias.

```js
function ValidarFormato(longitud_numero,evento_disparado){
 var ExpReg = new RegExp("^\d{" + longitud_numero + "}$");
 
  //Expresion regular con la que funciona
  //var patt = new RegExp(/^\d{4}$/);
  
  var valor = evento_disparado.value;
  
 console.log("Patron:"+ExpReg+" |Valor introducido:"+valor);
 if( !(ExpReg.test(valor)) ) {
  console.log("false");
  return false;
 }else{
  console.log("true");
  return true;
 }
}

function asignarEventos()
{
   if (document['readyState'] == 'complete')
   {
     //Input Entradad
    input_entrada = document.getElementById("input_entrada");
   //Boton Buscar 
   btn_entrada = document.getElementById("btn_entrada");
    btn_entrada.addEventListener('click',function(){
    ValidarFormato(4,input_entrada);
    });
 }
}
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', asignarEventos, false);
```

```html
 <input  id="input_entrada"></input>
 <button  id="btn_entrada">Entrada</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia esta línea:

```
var ExpReg = new RegExp("^\d{" + longitud_numero + "}$");
```

**Por:**

```
var ExpReg = new RegExp("^\\d{" + longitud_numero + "}$");
```

> Es decir añádele otro backslash delante de la **d**

Según la página: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp#Description

Cuando se usa la función constructor, la cadena de escape de reglas normal (precedida del caracter especial \ cuando incluye un string) es necesaria. Por ejemplo, lo siguiente es equivalente:

```
var re = new RegExp("\\w+");
var re = /\w+/;
```